# Converting date from mm/dd/yyyy which is read from excel to yyyy/mm/dd before sending it to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, date

I am importing an Excel sheet into a SQL Server database. I am able to upload the data but there is a column in Excel which consists of dates in format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I want this to be converted to `yyyy/mm/dd` before sending it to database :

```
DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
dt7.Load(dr);
DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];

// Bulk Copy to SQL Server
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
{
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";
  dt7.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)
  {
    DateTime oldDate =Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelRows[i]["data"]).Date;
    DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate).Date;
    ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
  }
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);
```

> Error at: DateTime oldDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelRows[i]["data"]).Date;
>   Error: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

It seems to me that it is reading wrong column or something since it says `cannot be cast from DBnull`. The Excel sheet has two columns:

```
id | data (which is date)
```

I have tried replacing `ExcelRows[i]["data"]` with `ExcelRows[i][1]` but I got the same error.

Comment: First of all: `DATETIME` in SQL Server **doesn't have** any formatting associated with it - it's just an 8-byte binary value. All you need to make sure is that the importing code can interpret the incoming strings as valid dates. Secondly: the error says that you're reading a `DBNull` - e.g. there's a row where there is **no data** for that cell - you cannot convert `DBNull` to anything - so you need to check for `... != DBNull.Value` before converting to avoid those NULLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because ExcelRows[i]["data"] returns DBNull.

You should handle it when that happens

```
    if (ExcelRows[i]["data"] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        // Include any actions to perform if there is no date
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime oldDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelRows[i]["data"]).Date;
        DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate).Date;
        ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code, the values are going to the database now there is no error BUT 
excel value:  11/25/1999
database :  11/25/1999 12:00:00 AM   :( Plus the first row in database table is null although its not null in excel

Comment: For some strange reason the values in table are 11/25/1999 12:00:00 AM but when i view table using select * from query i get 1999/11/25 00:00:00

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see your comment earlier. Did you manage to solve your problem? What is the database column type that you are trying to insert? If it is a date type, then it could just be the format of the display of dates.

Comment: Yeah well its DateTime i had been banging my head all this while and then i noticed that when i query it gives me 1999/11/25 00:00:00 so probably its the database which is adding it so the problem is solved i guess thanks!